# How do I keep Javascript/JQuery from moving other elements on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I get the animation code to not un-hide the div of text, that should work only on toggling show/hide buttons? After I added the animate code to my js page, it messed up the other jquery I had for show/hide div text.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    $("#data").hide();
    $('#show').show();
    $('#hide').css('display', 'none');
  });
  $("#show").click(function() {
    $("#data").show();
    $("#hide").show();
    $('#show').css('display', 'none');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    var div = $("div");
    div.animate({
      height: '300px',
      opacity: '0.4'
    }, "slow");
    div.animate({
      width: '300px',
      opacity: '0.8'
    }, "slow");
    div.animate({
      height: '100px',
      opacity: '0.4'
    }, "slow");
    div.animate({
      width: '100px',
      opacity: '0.8'
    }, "slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
<div id="data">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</div>
<button id="button" style="position:absolute;top:500px;left:0px;">Start Animation</button>
<div id="div" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;">
</div>
```

Comment: You mean to only animate your square? Then correct your selector like this `$('#div')`

Comment: is this what you're trying to do? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqPooV

Comment: Indenting your code would be helpful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

1st `id="div"` selector should be `$("#div")`

2nd your button are overlapping, remove `position:absolute` from `<button>` style

3rd if you don't want the text div to show, comment it out or remove `//$("#data").show();` from `$("#show")` click event

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    $("#data").hide();
    $('#show').show();
    $('#hide').css('display', 'none');
  });
  $("#show").click(function() {
    //$("#data").show();
    $("#hide").show();
    $('#show').css('display', 'none');
  });
  
  $("#button").click(function() {
    var div = $("#div");
    div.animate({
      height: '300px',
      opacity: '0.4'
    }, "slow");
    div.animate({
      width: '300px',
      opacity: '0.8'
    }, "slow");
    div.animate({
      height: '100px',
      opacity: '0.4'
    }, "slow");
    div.animate({
      width: '100px',
      opacity: '0.8'
    }, "slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
<div id="data">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</div>
<button id="button" style="top:500px;left:0px;">Start Animation</button>
<div id="div" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;">
</div>
```